# Is there an open source MemoryStream implementation that does not use contiguous memory?

Tags: c#, .net, memorystream

[Like GuyFawkes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042567/memorystream-out-of-memory-c-sharp), I would like to use MemoryStream to store a large amount of data, but keep encountering the 'out of memory' exceptions.
TomTom's answer is what I would like to do - use an implementation that does not require a contiguous block - but I'm wondering if there is already a free implementation available, to save me writing one myself?

**Does anyone know of a good, free re-implementation of MemoryStream that can work with large streams?**

EDIT:

The MemoryMappedFile solution is very interesting and I will be remembering it for other projects, however as Henk says, it strays too far from the abstraction that MemoryStream is aiming for. Specifically, the requirement of a known capacity.
The data that the replacement shall handle will in some cases be very large, but in others relatively small (and no we don't know which it will be until its too late ;)); further, many instances of the class will be in existence at the same time.
Ultimately the work required to use MemoryMappedFiles (to determine an appropriate size for each one) would be equivalent to that of implementing TomTom's solution.

Comment: A similar problem in StringBuilder was fixed in .NET 4 by altering the implementation to use ropes.  Googling "memorystream rope" just produces hits of programmers that are at the end of one.  A 64-bit operating system is the hundred dollar solution.

Comment: OK, I have taken the lack of (bar Eric and dtb's which were interesting but not quite what I needed) answers as a 'no' and so have implemented it myself. Its not particularly complicated but I'll upload it if someone could suggest the best place?

Comment: @HansPassant, ropes are an interesting read, Thanks (Even if Googling "memorystream rope" is not exactly inspiring!) For my project though I only needed streams in the order of hundreds of megabytes, so a simple list in my implementation sufficed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my implementation in case anyone needs it; I will leave this question open for a bit in case someone still responds with anything better.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/348590/A-replacement-for-MemoryStream

Answer (score 1):

You yould create a [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) without a file, i.e. one that lives in system memory.
 The [DelayAllocatePages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfileoptions.aspx) option delays allocations until the memory is actually needed. You need to specify a maximum capacity in advance though. Use the [CreateViewStream Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267538.aspx) to create a stream.

Comment: Thank you to you and Eric; I tried to implement the MemoryMappedFile solution, but it is not quite suitable for this case however (I have added extra detail to the question to explain).

Comment: Doesn’t this still require exactly the same amount of contiguous virtual address space within your process, thus not solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a re-implementation of MemoryStream, but consider whether you can use a [Memory Mapped File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) for your requirement.

Memory Mapped Files can solve many of the classes of problems that large memory buffers can solve, are very efficient, and are supported directly by .NET.

Comment: AFAIK memory-mapped files must have a fixed size.

Comment: Are you sure? I’m fairly confident that memory-mapped files require a contiguous chunk of virtual address space in your process. They don’t help solve this problem.